# Change background image URL when you scroll over a text link?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with a code. I've tried in different ways and checking other solutions in here to try to change them to my needs but I'm still learning Javascript and I can't find a way to do it.

What I'd like to do is for the image on the left to change when you scroll over the text on the right. For example, if you scroll over "Rules", the little box on the left should change to the checkmark (and of course, the rest should do the same).

The way we did it was by making the images be a background-image inside a div, but we aren't entirely sure if that's the best option. I left there my latest try with an "onmouseover" but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for reading.

```js
function CTHOVER2() {
  if (getElementById('2').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/TSoKZYw.jpg')";) {
    getElementById('2').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/zRVjd5a.jpg')";
  }
}
```

```css
.caretakergoalsText {
  color: #b4ac7d;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.caretakergoalsText:hover {
  color: #e4d08a;
  transition: color 1s;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.caretakergoalsImage {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/TSoKZYw.jpg');
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.caretakergoalsImage:hover {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/zRVjd5a.jpg');
}

.caretakergoalsImageACTIVE {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/zRVjd5a.jpg');
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.caretakergoalsclear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.deviantart.com/divinejaws/journal/NEWS-752251501">
  <div class="caretakergoalsImageACTIVE"></div>
  <div class="caretakergoalsText">News</div>
</a>
<div class="caretakergoalsclear"></div>
<a href="https://www.deviantart.com/divinejaws/journal/RULES-756241294">
  <div class="caretakergoalsImage" id="2"></div>
  <div class="caretakergoalsText" onmouseover="CTHOVER2();">Rules</div>
</a>
<div class="caretakergoalsclear"></div>
<a href="https://www.deviantart.com/divinejaws/journal/STORY-753110913">
  <div class="caretakergoalsImage"></div>
  <div class="caretakergoalsText">About</div>
</a>
<div class="caretakergoalsclear"></div>
<a href="#">
  <div class="caretakergoalsImage"></div>
  <div class="caretakergoalsText">Events</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/ohqtjvuw/8/

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('caretakergoalsText')).forEach(item => {
console.log(item.parentNode.querySelector(".caretakergoalsImage, .caretakergoalsImageACTIVE"))
item.onmouseenter = (evt) => evt.target.parentNode.querySelector(".caretakergoalsImage, .caretakergoalsImageACTIVE").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/zRVjd5a.jpg')";
item.onmouseleave = (evt) => evt.target.parentNode.querySelector(".caretakergoalsImage, .caretakergoalsImageACTIVE").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/TSoKZYw.jpg')";})
```

I put in there smallest changes. I think is one a good way to make hover on brother element but there is plenty of others.